# How can I convert my model.ckpt file into single .ckpt file and How can i test my model to predict image score?

Tags: tensorflow

I am training an inception model from scratch using flowers dataset. Using the scripts provided by tensorflow models. The output of the training are these files:

```
checkpoint
events.out.tfevents.xxxxxx
model.ckpt-xxxx.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-xxxx.index
model.ckpt-xxxx.meta

model.ckpt-xxxx.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-xxxx.index
model.ckpt-xxxx.meta
```

These were some of the files I got. Does someone have a script to convert these files in something I can use to classify my images? How can I use it to test my own image ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a three step process.

Step 1: Hope you already have tensorflow models directory, since you trained from it. Run the following command pertaining to the models directory you have:

```
python models/research/slim/export_inference_graph.py --model_name=<MODEL_NAME> --output_file=<NAME_OF_PB_FILE_CREATED> --dataset_dir=<PATH_TO_TF_RECORDS_DIRECTORY>
```

Eg:

```
python models/research/slim/export_inference_graph.py --model_name=inception_v3 --output_file=/home/user1/inception_v3_inf_graph.pb --dataset_dir=/home/user1/tfRecords
```

Step 2: Clone tensorflow github repository. (git clone `https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git` ). 
Run the following commands w.r.t to the cloned tensorflow directory as below:

```
python tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py --input_graph=<PATH_TO_PB_FILE_CREATED_IN_STAGE1> --input_checkpoint=<PATH_TO_CKPT_FILES_GENERATED_DURING_TRAINING> --input_binary=true --output_graph=<PATH_TO_SAVE_OUTPUT_FROZEN_GRAPH> --output_node_names=<OUTPUT_NODE_NAMES_OF_MODEL>
```

Eg:

```
python tensorflow/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py --input_graph=/home/user1/inception_v3_inf_graph.pb --input_checkpoint=/home/user1/model.ckpt-50000 --input_binary=true --output_graph=/home/user1/frozen_inception_v3.pb --output_node_names=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Please note the number 50000 in the example. This indicates the number of iterations. If you have trained your model for 10 iterations, then it would be 10. Also, even though there are 3 types of files for each checkpoint (meta, data & index), we just mention the first part. The rest will be parsed by the script automatically.

Step 3: Run the following commands w.r.t to the cloned tensorflow directory as below:

```
python tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py --image=<PATH_TO_TEST_IMAGE_FILE> --input_layer=input --output_layer=<MODEL_OUTPUT_LAYER_NAME> --graph=<PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH_CREATED_IN_STAGE2> --labels=<PATH_TO_LABELS_FILE> --input_mean=<MEAN> --input_std=<STD_DEVIATION>
```

Eg:

```
python tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py --image=/home/user1/test_img.jpg --input_layer=input --output_layer=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1 --graph=/home/user1/frozen_inception_v3.pb --labels=/home/user1/labels.txt --input_mean=0 --input_std=255
```

The last one will give you the prediction result of test_img.jpg